# how can i acess a variable outside of an if statement in java

Tags: java, variables

i have defined a variable inside an if statement and I am trying to access it outside of that if statement now. now the error is saying that it cannot find the symbol which is because its being defined as an intance variable, is there a way i can change it so i can access it outside the variable? heres the code

```
if((e.getSource()==userOrder2)&& (orderType==1))
{
     String buyO= userOrder2.getText();
     int buyOrder= Integer.parseInt(buyO); //variable im trying to access
}

// trying to use buyOrder in a different if statement
if(orderType==1 && (stockPrice <= buyOrder))
{
     orderResult.setText("The Stock" + (stockName2.getText()) + "was bought at" + stockPrice);
}
```

Comment: You don't really understand the concept of scope huh?

Comment: sorry im a freshman in high school, im just looking for some extra things to work on.

Comment: ~ Then in that case consider reading up on scope. Additionally, I would heartily recommend you read `Code Complete 2` as a "personal semester" before you write a lot more code. Being in high school and wanting to write code, it'll be a fast read over a few weekends. At least do the first 400 pages. The rest of the book may not be where you are right now, but those are pretty well gonna cover all your important bases. ~~ Additionally, once you've earned a few more upvotes, come on over to the chat area and get hooked ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use it as

```
 int buyOrder= 0;
 if((e.getSource()==userOrder2)&& (orderType==1)){
     String buyO= userOrder2.getText();
     buyOrder= Integer.parseInt(buyO);
 }
 if(orderType==1 && (stockPrice <= buyOrder))
```

Java uses [block](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html) level local variable scopes. A variable has to be declared in a scope which is common for all the places where you want to use it.

In your case the variable the scope of the variable `buyOrder` is limited to the block `if((e.getSource()==userOrder2)&& (orderType==1)){...}`, so it is not available outside the if block. Here we need to declare the variable out side the `if((e.getSource()==userOrder2)&& (orderType==1)){...}` so that it can be accessed outside of the block.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it outside (before) the `if` statement.

Comment: sorry, i should have made it clearer. i only want the variable to be created if it meets those parameters, so it needs to be inside the if statement right?

Comment: No.. this is because of the scope of the variable `orderType` is limited to the if block in which it is defined so it cannot be accessed outside. In your case if the variable is created only if the `if((e.getSource()==userOrder2)&& (orderType==1))` condition is satisfied then I think the condition ` if(orderType==1 && (stockPrice <= buyOrder))` also should be inside  `if((e.getSource()==userOrder2)&& (orderType==1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare outsite the if statement.

```
int buyOrder;
if((e.getSource()==userOrder2)&& (orderType==1))
{
    String buyO= userOrder2.getText();
        buyOrder= Integer.parseInt(buyO); //variable im trying to access
}

  if(orderType==1 && (stockPrice <= buyOrder))
```

Comment: i tried that but im getting an error message that says that the variable is already defined

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean trouble = true;

int buyOrder;
if((e.getSource()==userOrder2)&& (orderType==1)) {
    String buyO= userOrder2.getText();
    buyOrder= Integer.parseInt(buyO); //variable im trying to access
    trouble = false;
}

if(orderType==1 && (stockPrice <= buyOrder)) {
 if (!trouble) {
  //Do what you need.
 } else {
  //Bail out.
 }
}
```